# How to add myself to sudoers when accidently remove main user out of the sudo group

Tags: permissions, sudo, password, root, groups

I was trying to create a public and private share directory using samba and I ended up accidently relocated my main user to smbshare group and can no longer use sudo commands or log in as root. I will not be able to get into recovery mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to [boot into recovery mode](https://ostechnix.com/how-to-boot-into-rescue-mode-or-emergency-mode-in-ubuntu-18-04/), mount your filesystem and edit the `/etc/sudoers` file. You can also do similar from live media.

Comment: If you know root user's password, you can use `su` to log in as root then edit `/etc/sudoers`.